# Find a certain value from a source collection in a target collection of different type with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to know wether ONE of the sourceList values after the semicolon is contained in the targetList identified by the Name property. If thats true the bool value must be returned.

Its not working but I tried something...

I guess my linq is not correct the .All thingie...

The "FoundSomething" is contained in the targetList so it should return TRUE.

```
var sourceList = new String[]
{ 
    "1;HideButton",
    "2;ShowButton",
    "3;HideButton",
    "4;ShowButton",
    "5;HideButton",
    "6;ShowButton",
    "7;HideButton",
    "8;ShowButton",
    "9;HideButton",
    "10;FoundSomething",
};

var targetList = new List<GlobalConfiguration>()
{
    new GlobalConfiguration{ Name = "444" },
    new GlobalConfiguration{ Name = "fdsdffd" },
    new GlobalConfiguration{ Name = "44" },
    new GlobalConfiguration{ Name = "fsdd" },
    new GlobalConfiguration{ Name = "fs4rtref" },
    new GlobalConfiguration{ Name = "ftrtras" },
    new GlobalConfiguration{ Name = "FoundSomething" },
};

Boolean exists = sourceList.Any(a => targetList.All(c => c.Name == a.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want another `Any` instead of `All`:

```
bool exists = sourceList
    .Select(s => s.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last())
    .Any(v => targetList.Any(t => s == t.Name));
```

Comment: ah yes I thought about it but did not follow the idea. Thanks. Your code works and I prefer it over Christophers solution because its  one linq method call less.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're aiming at, but here's my best guess:

```
sourceList
    .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last())
    .Intersect(targetList.Select(x => x.Name))
    .Any();
```

What this does is it creates two sequences

1. The second half of the `sourceList` (after the semi-colon)
2. The name property of the `targetList`

with `Select`.

Then it uses `Intersect` to return any items that the two sequences share in common.

Finally it uses `Any` to determine if anything was returned from `Intersect` (Which I assume is readily understandable).

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two sets, and you want to see if their intersection is not empty. You should do just that, thanks to the handy [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension method.

```
var source = sourceList.Select(s=>s.Split(';')[1]);
var target = targetList.Select(t=>t.Name);

return source.Intersect(target).Count() > 0;
```

Comment: You should use `Any` rather than Count() > 0.  It will shortcircuit and it's more descriptive of the goal of the code